What is the syntax for dropping an Amazon Aurora with mysql compatinility user with single quotes?
I'm using AWS 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.05.2
I do this to get a list of the users
SELECT user,host from mysql.user;

and have these entries, surrounded by single quotes ('...').
user                 |host     |
---------------------+---------+
‘user1’              |%        |
‘my_user’            |%        |

What is the syntax to drop them? I've tried
DROP user "'user1'"@'%';

or (from comments)
DROP user "\'user1\'"@'%';

But I get syntax errors.
SQL Error [1396] [HY000]: Operation DROP USER failed for '\'user1\''@'%'


The escape character is a backslash, try "'user1'"@"%";

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/string-literals.html

Do you use mysql or amazon aurora? The two are not the same, amazon rewrote significant parts of mysql for its aurora offering.

@sleepyhead I updated my post. I'm using AWS Aurora.

If those quotes are as described in your post, they're the so-called "smart quotes" and you should copy-paste that value exactly inside MySQL double quotes. If you're getting errors, please include the exact error text in your question.

That's not a syntax error. It just means the user doesn't exist.

Demo, using my local MySQL 8.0.39 instance:
mysql> create user '''user1'''@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select user from mysql.user;
+------------------+
| user             |
+------------------+
| 'user1'          |
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
| root             |
+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop user '''user1'''@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select user from mysql.user;
+------------------+
| user             |
+------------------+
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
| root             |
+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

If your user actually has smart-quotes, these are not the same characters as single-quotes. You don't have to do any escaping for smart-quotes.
mysql> create user '‘user1’'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select user from mysql.user;
+------------------+
| user             |
+------------------+
| ‘user1’          |
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
| root             |
+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop user '‘user1’'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select user from mysql.user;
+------------------+
| user             |
+------------------+
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
| root             |
+------------------+

